# Using multiple Jquery DataTables with individual tables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have this script to use with two individual tables:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    tbl = $('#listtableB').dataTable( {
        "bStateSave": true,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "aLengthMenu": [ [ 10, 25, 50, 100, 400, 800, -1 ], [ 10, 25, 50, 100, 400, 800, 'Összes' ] ],
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "oLanguage": {
                "sUrl": "lang/datatables_hu.txt"
            },
         "aoColumns": [
            { "bSortable": true },
            { "bSortable": true },
            { "bSortable": true },
            { "bSortable": false },
        ]
        })
    tbl.fnSort( [ [0,'asc'] ] );


        newsl = $('#listtableD').dataTable( {
        "bStateSave": true,
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "aLengthMenu": [ [ 10, 25, 50, 100, 400, 800, -1 ], [ 10, 25, 50, 100, 400, 800, 'Összes' ] ],
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "oLanguage": {
                "sUrl": "lang/datatables_hu.txt"
            },
         "aoColumns": [
            { "bSortable": true },
            { "bSortable": true },
            { "bSortable": false }
        ]
        })
    newsl.fnSort( [ [0,'asc'] ] );


    })


</script>
```

But only the first table changes, the second stays normal table, but if I delete the first datatable settings, the second became changed. Why is it not working with the two tables?

Comment: Are you getting an error ?

Comment: Try to declare `newsl` and `tbl`

Comment: If one will work without the other, I would make sure they're being declared like Mr. Lohmann has Suggested, and if that doesn't solve your problem, I would investigate the elements to check for duplicate id's somewhere.